# How to get registration id for FCM from WebView app for iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, webview, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a mobile app for iOS using WebView where user login to our rails backend. I need to somehow transfer registration id to my rails backend after user login in the WebView. How could I do that? Basically, I thought about two ways: 
 1. intercept all request from WebView to the server and add custom header with registration id (unfortunately I googled, that this is not possible in iOS, only in android). 
 2. Add it to request via javascript, but I have no idea how to get it in WebView js (in android there is javascript interface for this, but in iOS I didn`t find anything similar).

So any ideas how to send registration id from ios app to my backend and connect it with a logged user?